# StrongTypingException in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-objects

Anybody can tell why the ToList() throws an exception?

```
var duplicates =  
    from typeMappings in _liveTable.Where(r =>
        (r.ProviderId == providerId) && (r.ExchangeId == exchangeId))
    join dataDictionary in _liveDataSet.DataDictionary.Where(r => 
        (r.DataDictionaryTypeId == dataDictionaryTypeId)) 
    on typeMappings.DataDictionaryId equals dataDictionary.DataDictionaryId
    select typeMappings.ConfigId;

if (duplicates.ToList().Count > 0) 
{ ... }
```

The Exception message is:
    'duplicates.ToList()' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException' System.Collections.Generic.List {System.Data.StrongTypingException}

Thanks

Comment: What is the message of the exception?

Comment: btw, what flavor of Linq is it? Entity Framework? Linq to objects?

Comment: I have added the exception. not sure about the flavor of Linq. I guess Linq to objects. _liveTable is a table in a DataSet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:

> [StrongTypingException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.strongtypingexception.aspx)
>
> The exception that is thrown by a strongly typed DataSet when the user accesses a DBNull value.

So the problem occurs because one of the properties you access in the query is null. Check which properties of your `DataTable` are allowed to be null, and check it with a call to [`IsNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx) before you try to get the value.

Comment: instead of writing things like `r.ProviderId == providerId`, write `!r.IsNull("ProviderId") && r.ProviderId == providerId`

Comment: Is there any way to express this without having to provide the column name as a string? !r.IsNull("ProviderId")

Comment: @MarkMaslar, typically, in a strongly typed dataset, nullable properties also have an associated method to check if it's null (I don't have the exact name in mind), so you don't need to pass the name as a string

Answer (score 0):

Try to use that to eleminate Null value

```
var duplicates =  
from typeMappings in _liveTable.Where(r =>
    (r.ProviderId == providerId) && (r.ExchangeId == exchangeId))
join dataDictionary in _liveDataSet.DataDictionary.Where(r => 
    (r.DataDictionaryTypeId == dataDictionaryTypeId)) 
on typeMappings.DataDictionaryId equals dataDictionary.DataDictionaryId
select new
       { ConfigId = typeMappings.ConfigId = null ? "anyValueyouwhant" : typeMappings.ConfigId};
```

juste to test without null value

Comment: but this will not give me the real result, right? I would get "anyValueyouwhant" even though there are duplicates I guess..

Comment: you can use it to be sure that your probleme with the null value. and to get the real result you have to revise your code to not make null value;